# Elastic analyzer to enable matching searches such as C#, C++, A+

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a custom analyzer in elastic search to enable matching terms such as C#, C++, A+ currently it will only match C, C, A.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_custom_analyzer": {
                "type": "keyword", 
                "type_table": [
                    "# => ALPHANUM",
                    "+ => ALPHANUM"
                ],
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase"
                ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to analyze the index using the following:

```
{
"analyzer": "my_custom_analyzer",
"text": "CSS, A++, C#.Net, ASP.Net Hospitals is Africa's leading and the fastest growing super specialty care and multi-organ transplantation hospital. Designed the User Interfaces, User Controls according the requirements\n· Developed Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) for User Interface uniformity throughout the   application\n· Involved in programming the business logic layer and data access layer\n· Involved in in developing pages in ASP.Net with C#.Net"
}
```

Result:

```
{
"tokens": [
    {
    "token": "CSS, A++, C#.Net, ASP.Net Hospitals is Africa's leading and the fastest growing super specialty care and multi-organ transplantation hospital. Designed the User Interfaces, User Controls according the requirements\n· Developed Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) for User Interface uniformity throughout the   application\n· Involved in programming the business logic layer and data access layer\n· Involved in in developing pages in ASP.Net with C#.Net",
    "start_offset": 0,
    "end_offset": 443,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 0
    }
]
}
```

Also I am not sure how to enable the analyzer, should this be done in mappings?

```
{
    "properties": {
        "attachment.content": {
            "type": "my_custom_analyzer"
        }
    }
}
```

Response when trying to use it in mappings:

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
    {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "No handler for type [my_custom_analyzer] declared on field [attachment.content]"
    }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "No handler for type [my_custom_analyzer] declared on field [attachment.content]"
},
"status": 400
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: another one i would like to match on is .NET

Comment: Shouldn't your type table things part of `char filters`?

Comment: @louis_coetzee can you provide for your text, what are your expected tokens ?

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies. Not really clued up, still figuring ou ES. But was expecting ["a+", "c#", "c++"] - basically if I do a search now with highlighting I only get ["a", "c"] - hope I am talking sense.

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja hi, I am using ingest attachments plugin to index CV's in full text and would like to be able to match on C#, currently it's ignoring the # and only matching on C.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a proper response from ES api using the following, it's not 100% yet, but it's on the right track, it's currently not highlighting which is a problem, but when using the analyzer api to test I get a response which i think is in the right direction.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
                    "filter": {
                        "my_delimeter": {
                            "type": "word_delimiter",
                            "type_table": [
                                "# => ALPHANUM",
                                "+ => ALPHANUM",
                                ". => ALPHANUM"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "analyzer": {
                            "my_analyzer": {
                                    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                                "filter": ["lowercase", "my_delimeter"]
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Text that I am analyzing:

```
{
    "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
    "text": "CSS, A++, C#.Net, ASP.Net Hospitals is Africa's leading and the fastest growing super specialty care and multi-organ transplantation hospital. Designed the User Interfaces, User Controls according the requirements\n· Developed Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) for User Interface uniformity throughout the   application\n· Involved in programming the business logic layer and data access layer\n· Involved in in developing pages in ASP.Net with C#.Net"
}
```

Response:

```
{
"tokens": [
    {
    "token": "css",
    "start_offset": 0,
    "end_offset": 3,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 0
    },
    {
    "token": "a++",
    "start_offset": 5,
    "end_offset": 8,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 1
    },
    {
    "token": "c#.net",
    "start_offset": 10,
    "end_offset": 16,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 2
    },
    {
    "token": "asp.net",
    "start_offset": 18,
    "end_offset": 25,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 3
    },
    {
    "token": "hospitals",
    "start_offset": 26,
    "end_offset": 35,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 4
    },
    {
    "token": "is",
    "start_offset": 36,
    "end_offset": 38,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 5
    },
    {
    "token": "africa",
    "start_offset": 39,
    "end_offset": 45,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 6
    },
    {
    "token": "leading",
    "start_offset": 48,
    "end_offset": 55,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 7
    },
    {
    "token": "and",
    "start_offset": 56,
    "end_offset": 59,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 8
    },
    {
    "token": "the",
    "start_offset": 60,
    "end_offset": 63,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 9
    },
    {
    "token": "fastest",
    "start_offset": 64,
    "end_offset": 71,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 10
    },
    {
    "token": "growing",
    "start_offset": 72,
    "end_offset": 79,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 11
    },
    {
    "token": "super",
    "start_offset": 80,
    "end_offset": 85,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 12
    },
    {
    "token": "specialty",
    "start_offset": 86,
    "end_offset": 95,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 13
    },
    {
    "token": "care",
    "start_offset": 96,
    "end_offset": 100,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 14
    },
    {
    "token": "and",
    "start_offset": 101,
    "end_offset": 104,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 15
    },
    {
    "token": "multi",
    "start_offset": 105,
    "end_offset": 110,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 16
    },
    {
    "token": "organ",
    "start_offset": 111,
    "end_offset": 116,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 17
    },
    {
    "token": "transplantation",
    "start_offset": 117,
    "end_offset": 132,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 18
    },
    {
    "token": "hospital.",
    "start_offset": 133,
    "end_offset": 142,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 19
    },
    {
    "token": "designed",
    "start_offset": 143,
    "end_offset": 151,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 20
    },
    {
    "token": "the",
    "start_offset": 152,
    "end_offset": 155,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 21
    },
    {
    "token": "user",
    "start_offset": 156,
    "end_offset": 160,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 22
    },
    {
    "token": "interfaces",
    "start_offset": 161,
    "end_offset": 171,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 23
    },
    {
    "token": "user",
    "start_offset": 173,
    "end_offset": 177,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 24
    },
    {
    "token": "controls",
    "start_offset": 178,
    "end_offset": 186,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 25
    },
    {
    "token": "according",
    "start_offset": 187,
    "end_offset": 196,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 26
    },
    {
    "token": "the",
    "start_offset": 197,
    "end_offset": 200,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 27
    },
    {
    "token": "requirements",
    "start_offset": 201,
    "end_offset": 213,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 28
    },
    {
    "token": "developed",
    "start_offset": 216,
    "end_offset": 225,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 29
    },
    {
    "token": "cascading",
    "start_offset": 226,
    "end_offset": 235,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 30
    },
    {
    "token": "style",
    "start_offset": 236,
    "end_offset": 241,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 31
    },
    {
    "token": "sheets",
    "start_offset": 242,
    "end_offset": 248,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 32
    },
    {
    "token": "css",
    "start_offset": 250,
    "end_offset": 253,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 33
    },
    {
    "token": "for",
    "start_offset": 255,
    "end_offset": 258,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 34
    },
    {
    "token": "user",
    "start_offset": 259,
    "end_offset": 263,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 35
    },
    {
    "token": "interface",
    "start_offset": 264,
    "end_offset": 273,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 36
    },
    {
    "token": "uniformity",
    "start_offset": 274,
    "end_offset": 284,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 37
    },
    {
    "token": "throughout",
    "start_offset": 285,
    "end_offset": 295,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 38
    },
    {
    "token": "the",
    "start_offset": 296,
    "end_offset": 299,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 39
    },
    {
    "token": "application",
    "start_offset": 302,
    "end_offset": 313,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 40
    },
    {
    "token": "involved",
    "start_offset": 316,
    "end_offset": 324,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 41
    },
    {
    "token": "in",
    "start_offset": 325,
    "end_offset": 327,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 42
    },
    {
    "token": "programming",
    "start_offset": 328,
    "end_offset": 339,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 43
    },
    {
    "token": "the",
    "start_offset": 340,
    "end_offset": 343,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 44
    },
    {
    "token": "business",
    "start_offset": 344,
    "end_offset": 352,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 45
    },
    {
    "token": "logic",
    "start_offset": 353,
    "end_offset": 358,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 46
    },
    {
    "token": "layer",
    "start_offset": 359,
    "end_offset": 364,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 47
    },
    {
    "token": "and",
    "start_offset": 365,
    "end_offset": 368,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 48
    },
    {
    "token": "data",
    "start_offset": 369,
    "end_offset": 373,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 49
    },
    {
    "token": "access",
    "start_offset": 374,
    "end_offset": 380,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 50
    },
    {
    "token": "layer",
    "start_offset": 381,
    "end_offset": 386,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 51
    },
    {
    "token": "involved",
    "start_offset": 389,
    "end_offset": 397,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 52
    },
    {
    "token": "in",
    "start_offset": 398,
    "end_offset": 400,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 53
    },
    {
    "token": "in",
    "start_offset": 401,
    "end_offset": 403,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 54
    },
    {
    "token": "developing",
    "start_offset": 404,
    "end_offset": 414,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 55
    },
    {
    "token": "pages",
    "start_offset": 415,
    "end_offset": 420,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 56
    },
    {
    "token": "in",
    "start_offset": 421,
    "end_offset": 423,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 57
    },
    {
    "token": "asp.net",
    "start_offset": 424,
    "end_offset": 431,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 58
    },
    {
    "token": "with",
    "start_offset": 432,
    "end_offset": 436,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 59
    },
    {
    "token": "c#.net",
    "start_offset": 437,
    "end_offset": 443,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 60
    }
]
}
```

Tried these mappings:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "attachment.content": {
            "type": "text",
    "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer",
    "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
            "fields": {
                "content": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

still highlight response is:

```
"highlight": {
    "skills": [
    "<em>C</em>#",
    "Microsoft Visual Studio <em>C</em># (Windows Form and Web APP) and Java Eclipse"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a custom char filter in your analyzer, in the settings of your index:

```
"char_filter": {
        "languages_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": ["c++ => cpp", "C++ => cpp", "IT => _IT_", "a+ => ap", "A+ => ap", "C# => csharp", "c# => csharp"]
        }
      }
```

Then you will add this custom analyzer to the mapping of your field:

```
PUT my-index/_mapping
{
"properties": { 
"my-field": {
"type": "text", 
"analyzer": "m_custom_analyzer"
}
}
}
```

Note: You cannot change an analyzer on an existing field. You will have to add a new field or to reindex

Comment: Thank you, I'll check this out in the morning and leave feedback. I would prefer to not use cpp and rather c++, but have read about this solution before, so I'll give it a go.